# Cannot connect to camera service android emulator

Tags: android, android-camera, android-manifest

I set my emulator's back camera to "emulated". When I run my app, it returns a runtime exception saying "Cannot connect to camera service" on the line:

```
camera.open(-1);
```

Here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.protoderma"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
android:protectionLevel="normal"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.protoderma.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code it is hard to tell. But one potential problem I see is that you are passing a -1 to `Camera.open();`. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) you see that the value passed should be always greater than 0 if there is a camera available. Ckeck the AVD's configuration to see if in the camera drop down you can select something else besides emulated (i.e. webcam0)

Comment: Yes i am passing a -1 to Camera.open(). thanks.

so how do i open the back camera only?

Comment: `Camera.open()` (it doesn't take any parameters) will get a reference of the first back-facing camera

Comment: Not true, you should use Camera.open(0)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "not true"? Here are the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open()) for `open()`.